# returning to cordova app from browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser, ionic-framework

I have a simple app built with ionic framework. The app at some point opens a browser (system browser) for payment (external payment gateway) and post payment, there is a success button displayed by a script on my server i.e the script sends a html page to the browser post successful payment.

The html contains a 'button' saying go back to application. I want user to have the app reopened on clicking of that button.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the childbrowser/inappbrowser to deal with this. This is a perfect application.

You open the inappbrowser and take care of the payment forms on success you can then close the inappbrowser.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/